# using await to retrieve data

Tags: dart, async-await

I don't really understand how the await/async mechanism (in dart but I guess the question is relevant for any language actually).
I'm using the sqfentity library to manage a small database.

this lib is providing a select().toList() function which will query some DB rows and returns it as a list of object.

the returned function is actually returning a Future<List> allowing to run the query asynchronously.

I'm working with local DB so I'm not really concerned by access time issues, so I'd like to write a function returning a list,once the query has finished:

```
    List<Event> get_list() async{
      return await Event()
      .select()
      .toList()
    }
```

The problem is that an async function must return a Future<> object. However, if I understand well, the await will "wait" for the toList() function to finishes before returning, so I don't understand why I can't just return the List object.

In order to do my job, I used the fact that in dart, parameters are passed by reference, so I wrote some intermediate function

```
void fillList(List<Event> lst){
   lst.addAll(await Event()
      .select()
      .toList())
}
List<Event> get_list() {
      List<Event> lst;
      fillList(lst);
      return lst;
    }
```

which seems really not natural and probably a wrong way to do things. Any explanation on how to deal with await in dart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, if I understand well, the await will "wait" for the toList() function to finishes before returning, so I don't understand why I can't just return the List object.

When you do:

```dart
Future<Result> foo() async {
  var intermediateResult = await someAsynchronousOperation();
  var result = doOtherStuff(intermediateResult);
  ...
  return result;
}
```

`await` provides the appearance of pausing execution of `foo` until `someAsynchronousOperation()` completes.  It does not pause your entire program.  The point of an asynchronous operation is to allow the rest of your program to continue executing while you are waiting for it to complete.  This allows your program to continue to respond to user input.

Whenever you use `await`, it's actually syntactic sugar for returning a `Future`:

```dart
Future<Result> foo() {
  return someAsynchronousOperation().then((someIntermediateResult) {
    var result = doOtherStuff(intermediateResult);
    ...
    return result;
  });
}
```

`foo()` calls `someAsynchronousOperation()` (which itself returns a `Future`), registers a `.then()` completion callback on it to execute `doSomeOtherStuff()` later.  `foo()` then immediately returns the resulting `Future` to its own caller.

> ```dart
> void fillList(List<Event> lst){
>    lst.addAll(await Event()
>       .select()
>       .toList())
> }
> List<Event> get_list() {
>       List<Event> lst;
>       fillList(lst);
>       return lst;
>     }
> ```

That will not work.

1. `await` can be used only in a function declared with `async`.
2. Because `fillList` depends on a `Future`, it is inherently asynchronous.  However, by declaring it to return `void` instead of a `Future`, it is impossible for callers to be notified when `fillList` completes.
3. Once you fix `fillList` to return a `Future`, `get_list` needs to wait for that `Future` to complete before returning `lst`.  Since `get_list` would need to depend on a `Future`, it too is inherently asynchronous. (Asynchronous functions are contagious.)

Comment: I see, but then how should I proceed to sync with the output and actually wait for the completion of the async process before continuing? should I poll the Future status until it's done? I guess there's a better way to do it probably.

Comment: @davidguez You should not poll.  You should just register a completion callback with `await` and do your dependent work when the callback executes.  Each caller of an asynchronous function must `await` the `Future`.  That makes the caller asynchronous, so its own callers must `await` its returned `Future` too, and so on.  Eventually you will reach Dart's event loop, which will wait until all outstanding asynchronous operations have completed.

Comment: @davidguez Also see [Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) and [Dart asynchronous programming: Isolates and event loops](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a)

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure if I understood the question, but it depends on the return type of `Event().select();`. If it returns a `Future`, then you need to use the async/await combination, or the `then` callback. Otherwise, you can just return a list of `Event` directly.

You can also do something like:

```dart
    List<Event> get_list(){
      final List<Event> events = [];

// If Event().select() returns a Future
      Event()
      .select().then((result){
         events.addAll(result.toList());
      });

      return events;
    }
```

But the issue with this is that while `Event().select()` is still loading, the function will return an empty list, then when items are loaded, the function will come back and fill the list with the returned items. That's why something like:

```dart
    Future<List<Event>> get_list() async{
      final events = await Event().select();
      return events.toList();
    }
```

Is kind of better because if you want for example to show a spinner while items are loading, you can do that, also you can easily catch errors.